# How to pass any Google API service object to a deferred task in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api, task-queue

I'm currently developing an App Engine application using Drive v3 API, but this question applies to most of Google APIs.

As Drive API is somehow slow in certain operations, I want to separate each file-processing into different tasks. In order to do so, I'm using the deferred library to avoid serializing-deserializing parameters.

The main parameter is the already authorized Drive API service object (using service accounts & domain-wide authority) for a given user.

A simplified snippet of **code** looks like this:

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        # Authorize and get the Drive service 
        service = get_drive_service(keyfile, 'user@my-domain.com')

        # Iterate through all the (previously retrieved) file list
        for file_id in file_list:
            # Queue a new task by passing the function and its arguments
            deferred.defer(test_drive_service, service, file_id)


def test_drive_service(service, file_id):

    # Do a simple Drive operation
    response = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
    print response.get('name')
```

and *part* of my **app.yaml** file:

```
handlers:
    - url: /_ah/queue/deferred
    script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
    login: admin

builtins:
    - deferred: on
```

If I **don't use** `deferred.defer()`, and call the `test_drive_service()` function **directly**, there's no issue and I get the proper file and info correctly.

However, when using the deferred library, it raises the following error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting (...) returned "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.">
```

My quota is fine, so no daily limit is really reached.

What can be causing the issue? 
Is there any other specific way to correctly pass the service object to a task queue?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here's my authentication flow:

```
def get_drive_service(keyfile, user_email):
    '''Builds and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service 
    account that acts on behalf of the given user.

    @param keyfile: generated JSON containing the service account details
    @param user_email: the email of the user.
    @return: Drive API service instance
    '''
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keyfile, SCOPES)

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    return service
```

It's based on the [Google Server-to-server OAuth 2.0 docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests) (section "Other platforms"), and again, working fine when calling the function directly, instead of adding it to a task queue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the `service` is not being serialized/deserialized correctly. If the deserialized service object is missing its access token, that will explain the `403 Quota for unauthenticated use`.

You have a secondary issue that you need to deal with the eventuality that the access token expires before your queued task gets round to using it (this situation will raise a 401 status).

I don't know enough about python on AppEngine to suggest a simple solution. I suggest posting this is a new question tagged appengine/python/google-oauth.

A non-simple solution would be to create a new endpoint that the queued task can call to get an access token.

Another approach would be to move the auth flow into the deferred task. Because you are using a Service Account, auth doesn't require any user interaction.

Comment: A bad serializing-deserializing was my main guess as well. I found these two methods in the reference that might be relevant: https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery.Resource-class.html#__setstate__. The deferred library actually pickles the passed parameters, so I guess those methods are being called internally. Moving the auth flow inside the task would work, but it will spend too much quota due to the large number of files. I would need to investigate on the endpoint solution. Maybe storing and retrieving the service from Datastore/Memchache...

Comment: It's the access token that you need to be passing - memcache would be a good option. Again, I'm not familiar with the python library, but I would hope that it is possible to instantiate a service and then inject an access token. Either way, make sure your deferred task can cope with an expired access token.

Answer (score 0):

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Means that you are not authorized.  You haven't sent an access token with the request. Something is up with your authentication.

Which library are you using exactly I think you need to find a better service account example.  Sending the key file with the create of the service doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned, the Drive service works as expected when calling the function directly, but shows the error when deferring it. I'm using the `from_json_keyfile_dict()` function (in Python) to retrieve the credentials, to later authorize and build the service. I can edit the question to add that auth flow if you want, but I don't think that's the issue here. For some reason, the internal serializing-deserializing made by the deferred library is unauthenticating the user/service.

Comment: I think its a good idea that you add your auth flow.  No matter what that is what the error means.  You are not authenticate.  It could also be simply a matter that you are not applying the access token to the request you are making.  check service see if its actually getting an access token.

Comment: Ok, added. But as I pointed out before, that authorization flow is working perfectly in any other scenario except for this one (deferring/using task queues).